# Memory leaks from PubNub Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, pubnub

I am using pubnub to handle realtime updates on the front end of the application I am working on. User have been experiencing a lot of browser crashes specifically on windows chrome. I ran chrome profiler and discovered that pubnub is continuously creating event listeners until eventually the browser runs our of memory and crashes. Is there a way to manually clean up event listeners created by pubnub, or any other work around?

**EDIT**
I have also tried switching over to the websockets version and the problem gets worse.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello Punub</title>
  <script src="https://pubnub.a.ssl.fastly.net/pubnub.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <h1>Hello</h1>
 </body>

 <!-- Import PubNub Core Lib -->

 <!-- Use WebSocket Constructor for a New Socket Connection -->
 <script>(function() {
    /* 'wss://ORIGIN/PUBLISH_KEY/SUBSCRIBE_KEY/CHANNEL' */
    WebSocket  = PUBNUB.ws;
    var socket = new WebSocket('wss://pubsub.pubnub.com/PUB/SUB/CHANNEL')
   // On Message Receive
   socket.onmessage = function(evt) {
    console.log('socket receive');
    console.log(evt.data);
   }
   // On Socket Close
   socket.onclose = function() {
    console.log('socket closed');
   }
   // On Error
   socket.onerror = function() {
    console.log('socket error');
   }
   // On Connection Establish
   socket.onopen = function(evt) {
    console.log('socket open');
    // Send a Message!
    socket.send('hello world!');
   }
   // On Send Complete
   socket.onsend = function(evt) {
     console.log('socket send');
     console.log(evt);
   }
   console.log(socket)
})();</script>
</html>
```

[image: Chrome Profiler]

**EDIT 2** I have re-run the profiler with the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello Punub</title>
  <script src="https://pubnub.a.ssl.fastly.net/pubnub.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <h1>Hello</h1>
 </body>

 <!-- Import PubNub Core Lib -->

 <!-- Use WebSocket Constructor for a New Socket Connection -->
 <script>(function() {
    /* 'wss://ORIGIN/PUBLISH_KEY/SUBSCRIBE_KEY/CHANNEL' */
    WebSocket  = PUBNUB.ws;
    var socket = new WebSocket('wss://pubsub.pubnub.com/PUB/SUB/CHANNEL')
   // On Message Receive
   socket.onmessage = function(evt) {

   }
   // On Socket Close
   socket.onclose = function() {

   }
   // On Error
   socket.onerror = function() {

   }
   // On Connection Establish
   socket.onopen = function(evt) {
    // Send a Message!
    socket.send('hello world!');
   }
   // On Send Complete
   socket.onsend = function(evt) {

   }
})();</script>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: here's a gist that we're using to produce the same issue, no work-arounds that we've uncovered yet https://gist.github.com/bevanhunt/f6e1007a0604a24c8089

Comment: We have never seen any memory leaks before and no reports until this one. Engineering is reviewing this currently and we'll report back with results.

Comment: Edit your code to use https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-dev.js which points to the latest version of the SDK. The version you are using above points to v3.6.7 - we will be deprecating that CDN soon.

Answer (score 1):

## Testing System Utilization and Memory Profile with PubNub JavaScript SDK

You are measuring the **JS Heap** using browser debug console.  Very nice!  This is okay but you have to make an adjustment. An important issue for you to address with your test is to note that **`console.log(...)`** will cause memory ballooning.  This is a common issue https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=console.log%20memory%20usage -

For future tests make sure to exclude all **`console.log()`** execution *everywhere* in your code.

> Your **EDIT** from above includes several more **`console.log()`** lines which will emphasize the memory balloon effect.

### Update for Memory Profiling

I'm currently running the following test in Chrome web browser using the same timeline memory monitoring method based in your original stackoverflow post.

```
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-dev.js"></script>
<script>(function(){

    WebSocket  = PUBNUB.ws;
    var socket = new WebSocket('wss://pubsub.pubnub.com/demo/demo/CHANNEL')

   // On Message Receive
   socket.onmessage = function(evt) {}

   // On Socket Close
   socket.onclose = function() {}

   // On Error
   socket.onerror = function() {}

   // On Connection Establish
   socket.onopen = function(evt) {}

   // On Send Complete
   socket.onsend = function(evt) {}

})();</script>
```

As you can see from the image below the profile of your browser's `Timeline` tab with memory profiling enabled should appear as follows.

#### Result of Memory Profile WebSocket JavaScript on Browser

> **JavaScript Heap GC** will trigger periodically claiming used memory.
>
> [image: Memory Profiling WebSockets]
>
> **JavaScript Listeners** are an always increasing integer that reset to zero periodically.
>
> [image: JavaScript Listeners Increase and Start Fresh]

### Turn *off* `console.log()` when Memory Profiling JavaScript

The **critical** part here is that you exclude **`console.log`** from your test because you will get the following false results!

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
    console.log({a:document,b:window,c:document.body})
},100)
</script>
```

[image: Console Log Problem with JavaScript Memory Profiling]

> **`console.log` Problem** with JavaScript Memory Profiling efforts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,as mentioned in the edit I have removed the console.logs and re-tested. The original code I used was a copy and paste from the pubnub doc's at the following link pubnub.com/websockets . I'm a little baffled as to how such simple code could be causing the heap to steadily increase.

Comment: But removing the console statements resolved it, correct? The question you ask is one for browser applications in general though.

Comment: Edit 2 above has removed all console.logs and still produces the same effect.

Comment: I'll run the test as well and post an update shortly.

Comment: We are seeing very different results to this on several different machines - can you confirm what version Chrome you're using? Also, this doesn't solve our issue at all, we're in the process of removing pubnub from our app now due to this apparently pretty obvious memory leak that you're not acknowledging. Also I note that you're using a different version of the pubnub library for your test - pubnub-dev - rather than your currently released version. Even in this version however you can see that the event listeners are still trending upwards for no real reason.

Comment: skype:blum.stephen or email stephen@pubnub.com so we can walk through details.  My chrome is *Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit)*.  The JS lib `pubnub-dev.js` is **`v3.7.14`** (same as one you're using) and always the latest version.  It should be called `pubnub-latest.js` instead but we labeled it `pubnub-dev.js` as a warning that it is an always **changing** version.  If you can connect with me I might have another option for you stephen@pubnub.com

Comment: I added an example for you which shows a memory growth profile that matches.

Comment: Thanks for the chat follow up, really appreciate the support; will evaluate your information and report back.